# How to structure mySQL query to find related information sorted in a particular order

Tags: mysql

I have a number of tables in my database and I need help in structuring queries that are quick and efficient. With the different queries that I have written so far either the results have been inconsistent or to big (returning more information than I need and therefore, have to use PHP later to constraint the results). Here is the background.

Our database handles leads for the senior housing industry. Each lead has many notes (a sales history) that not only give a history of the sale but inform the user of the next follow up date (actionDate). There are also many different statuses (i.e., active, top 10, move in, etc.) each lead can be assigned to (though not at the same time). The status of a lead is a history of the progression of a lead through the sales process. We can see what status the lead was and when.

In the base "lead" table each lead has a Primary Key called "inquiryID" that auto increments. This key is referenced in most other tables to relate them to the "lead" table. Here is the structure of the "lead" table.

```
TABLE: lead (~500 rows)
+-------------------+------------+-------+--------+
|  Field            |  Type      |  Key  | Extra  |
+-------------------+------------+-------+--------+
|  inquiryID        |  int(11)   |  PK   |  AI    |
|  communityID      |  int(3)    |       |        |
|  initialDate      |  date      |       |        |  
|  inquirySource    |  tinytext  |       |        |
|  inquiryType      |  tinytext  |       |        |
+-------------------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Another table is titled "leadNote". This table handles the sales journal for each lead. Basically a salesperson would enter in the date the note was written (date) who is writing the note (salesCounselor), the note itself (note), who is to follow up with the lead (actionCounselor), and what date they will follow up (actionDate).

```
TABLE: leadNote (~15000 rows)
+-------------------+------------+-------+--------+
|  Field            |  Type      |  Key  | Extra  |
+-------------------+------------+-------+--------+
|  inquiryNoteID    |  int(11)   |  PK   |  AI    |
|  inquiryID        |  int(11)   |  FK   |        |
|  date             |  date      |       |        |
|  salesCounselor   |  tinytext  |       |        |
|  note             |  text      |       |        |
|  actionCounselor  |  int(5)    |       |        |
+-------------------+------------+-------+--------+
```

The final table I will reference is titled "leadStatusHistory". This table handles the history of the status of this lead. A lead can have many different statuses, but not at the same time. We want to be able to track what a lead's status is and when. A lead would have a status (leadStatus), a date the status was assigned to them (statusDate), and who assigned the status to them (author) among other gathered data.

```
TABLE: leadStatusHistory (~1200 rows)
+-------------------+-------------+-------+--------+
|  Field            |  Type       |  Key  | Extra  |
+-------------------+-------------+-------+--------+
|  historyID        |  int(11)    |  PK   |  AI    |
|  inquiryID        |  int(11)    |  FK   |        |
|  leadStatus       |  tintytext  |       |        |
|  date             |  datetime   |       |        |
|  communityID      |  int(3)     |       |        |
|  timestamp        |  timestamp  |       |        |
+-------------------+-------------+-------+--------+
```

My goal is to be able to run a query that returns the inquiryID, actionCounselor, actionDate, and current leadStatus. As I said earlier the many different queries that I have tried have brought mixed results. There are two types of ways that I want to gather this list. 1) find all leads that have a next contact date that is less than or equal to today (this is the list of leads scheduled to follow up with today). 2) find all leads that match a certain leadStatus currently (i.e., to look up all leads that are currently with a status of "move in".

This is how I would ORDER the tables to get the information that I am looking for.
1) Find inquiryID, actionCounselor (value in the actionCounselor column  on the most recently created "leadNote" row or "date" that is the greatest), actionDate (value in the actionDate column  on the most recently created "leadNote" row or "date" that is the greatest), and leadStatus (value in the leadStatus column on the most recently created "leadStatusHistory" row or "timestamp" that is the greatest) WHERE the actionDate (value in the actionDate column  on the most recently created "leadNote" row or "date" that is the greatest) is less than or equal to today.

2) Find inquiryID, actionCounselor (value in the actionCounselor column  on the most recently created "leadNote" row or "date" that is the greatest), actionDate (value in the actionDate column  on the most recently created "leadNote" row or "date" that is the greatest), and leadStatus (value in the leadStatus column on the most recently created "leadStatusHistory" row or "timestamp" that is the greatest) WHERE leadStatus (value in the leadStatus column on the most recently created "leadStatusHistory" row or "timestamp" that is the greatest) is equal to "move in".

Here are some examples of current and past queries with my comments as to what is wrong with them.

query #1:

```sql
SELECT 
    tt.inquiryID,
    tt.actionDate,
    tt.date,
    tt.actionCounselor,
  (SELECT 
            leadstatushistory.leadstatus
        FROM
            leadstatushistory
        WHERE
            leadstatushistory.inquiryID = tt.inquiryID AND leadstatushistory.historyID = (SELECT 
                    MAX(leadstatushistory.historyID) as historyID
                FROM
                    leadstatushistory
                WHERE
                    inquiryID = tt.inquiryID)) AS leadStatus
FROM
    leadnote tt
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        inquiryID,
            MAX(inquiryNoteID) as inquiryNoteID,
            MAX(leadnote.actionDate) AS actionDate
    FROM
        leadnote
    GROUP BY inquiryID) groupedtt ON tt.inquiryID = groupedtt.inquiryID AND tt.inquiryNoteID = groupedtt.inquiryNoteID
WHERE
    tt.actionDate <= '2012-08-27' AND tt.actionDate != '0000-00-00' AND (SELECT 
            leadstatushistory.leadstatus
        FROM
            leadstatushistory
        WHERE
            leadstatushistory.inquiryID = tt.inquiryID AND leadstatushistory.historyID = 
               (SELECT 
                    MAX(leadstatushistory.historyID) as historyID
                FROM
                    leadstatushistory
                WHERE
                    inquiryID = tt.inquiryID)) != 'Resident' AND tt.communityID = 4
GROUP BY tt.inquiryID
```

COMMENTS: Gave me the columns I needed, but have had complaints that now and then the "actionDate" column will not reflect the the date of the of the most recently created leadNote row and sometimes the leadStatus was wrong. For example, the max(historyID) for the leadStatusHistory table is not necessarily the most recent status that we want to find. Sometimes our employees will go back and fill in missing leadStatus for leads in the past. This creates a new leadStatusHistory row with a new auto increment historyID. In this case the most recent (or greatest historyID) does not have the greatest "leadStatusHistory.date", because the date the user entered in was a past date (filling in past information so our historical records are accurate). The exact same problem we have with entering notes into the leadNote table for past notes. The new auto increment inquiryNoteID does not necessarily match the row with the greatest "tt.date".

query #2:

```sql
SELECT 
    maxDate.inquiryID, maxDate.date, maxDate.actionDate, maxDate.actionCounselor
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        leadnote
    ORDER BY date DESC , type ASC, inquiryNoteID DESC) as maxDate
        LEFT JOIN
    staff ON maxDate.actionCounselor = staff.staffID
WHERE
    maxDate.communityID = 4
GROUP BY inquiryID
```

COMMENTS: Gave me the columns I needed, but it also finds the information for all leads. This wastes valuable time and makes the response slower. I then have to use PHP to constrain the data to show only those leads that have an actionDate of <= today and a date that isn't "0000-00-00" or I constrain the data to show only those leads with a leadStatus of "Move In". Again, this does give me the results that I am looking for, but it is slow. Also, if I add into the query "WHERE date<=[today] AND date != '0000-00-00'" in the subquery it changes the results so they are not accurate and then I still have to use PHP to constrain the results to show only those that are of the status that I am looking for.

By looking at the above information does anyone have any ideas of how to better structure my query so that I can quickly find the exact information that I am looking for. Or is there a way to change the structure or relationship of the tables to get the results I am looking for. Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you post some EXPLAIN outputs?

Comment: The body of your text mentions columns `leadNote.actionDate`, `leadStatusHistory.statusDate` and `leadStatusHistory.author` that do not appear in your table structure: is that an oversight?  You should also read about fetching [groupwise maxima](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > My goal is to be able to run a query that returns the inquiryID, actionCounselor, actionDate, and current leadStatus.

   You are seeking to find the [groupwise maxima](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) from your `leadNote` and `leadStatusHistory` tables: namely the records with the maximum dates within each group of `inquiryID`.

   You can achieve this with a query along the following lines:

   ```
   SELECT inquiryID, actionCounselor, actionDate, leadStatus
   FROM   (
              leadNote NATURAL JOIN (
                SELECT   inquiryID, MAX(actionDate) AS actionDate
                FROM     leadNote
                GROUP BY inquiryID
              ) AS t
           ) JOIN (
              leadStatusHistory NATURAL JOIN (
                SELECT   inquiryID, MAX(statusDate) AS statusDate
                FROM     leadStatusHistory
                GROUP BY inquiryID
              ) AS t
           ) USING (inquiryID)
   ```

   For the best performance, you should ensure that `leadNote` has a composite index on `(inquiryID, actionDate)` and that `leadStatusHistory` has a composite index on `(inquiryID, statusDate, leadStatus)`:

   ```
    ALTER TABLE leadNote ADD INDEX (inquiryID, actionDate);
    ALTER TABLE leadStatusHistory ADD INDEX (inquiryID, statusDate, leadStatus);
   ```
2. > There are two types of ways that I want to gather this list. 1) find all leads that have a next contact date that is less than or equal to today (this is the list of leads scheduled to follow up with today). 2) find all leads that match a certain leadStatus currently (i.e., to look up all leads that are currently with a status of "move in".

   1. Add `WHERE actionDate <= CURRENT_DATE`
   2. Add `WHERE leadStatus  = 'move in'`